# Provisioning a Limited Edition iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, provisioning

I'm developing an app that will have two versions: one on the app store, and a limited edition that will be given away in a contest to one winner. My question is, how do I provision an app to give away to just one person? I'm guessing I need their UDID, and have to send them an Ad-Hoc distribution provisioning profile; but does this mean I will have to keep sending them new profiles every time it expires?

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks,

chmod

Comment: I'm not aware of any legal way how to give away an app like that... You can always put your premium app in the appstore at the highest price possible and give away a gift code to the contest winner.

Comment: I like @mja 's answer a lot, actually. Though why not put it at a price you'd be willing to sell it at? Is it worth $50, to have it be special? Would a $50 gift be a sufficient prize to give away to the contest winner? Would you *mind* if somebody gave you $50 for your limited edition version? I don't know if $50 is the sweet spot, but there's some place where you could potentially make some money and also still have it be a limited enough edition to make it a tempting prize for your contest.

Comment: mja and DR: Just curious would you have to pay App Store the 30% fee even with gift?

Answer (score 1):

Ad Hoc distribution certificates expire.  Unless you want to give away a time-limited app (the duration of the Ad Hoc provision), the better option might be to gift the app to the winner's iTunes account, which will cost the developer 30%, or to use one of an App store app's 50 free redemption codes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to customize it.

If you have their UDID, you can check for it in code like this:

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

From there you could simply switch out graphics or functionality based on whether the device matches the UDID or not.

Note: `uniqueIdentifier` is depreciated as of iOS5. It still works and may still work well into the future, but there is no guarantee of that.